# nem explorer investigating a Tx

Tags: nem

I logged

```
const transactionHttp = new TransactionHttp(url)
const signed = initiator
    .sign(aggregateTransaction)
    console.log(signed.hash)
```

and received

```
B4B531D2FA3D4FA58EC1B1FFCF22961967143D117C8DB70A139F96D492A2F4F9
```

as a response as expected but I don't seem to be able to search for it using 
[this tool](http://beta.catapult.mijin.io/explorer#).
There doesn't appear to be an input field.

What is the correct procedure for investigating a `Tx` ?

Answer (score 2):

The block explorer is in beta state and does not offer this feature. You can use the [nem2-cli](https://nemtech.github.io/cli/overview.html) to check your transaction.

After you installed the nem2-cli you can use this command:

`nem2-cli transaction info --profile <your profile> --hash <the transaction hash>`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have that logged in my app . What I was looking at was more along the lines of an etherscan type verification. That a client could view for example. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

After you sign the transaction you would need to announce it to the network. Only then you can look it up in the block explorer

```
const transactionHttp = new TransactionHttp(url)
const signed = initiator
    .sign(aggregateTransaction)
transactionHttp.announce(signed).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Source: http://beta.catapult.mijin.io/docs/guides/transaction.html